# Changing controls using a text box

Tags: c#, input, xna

I've been working on a method of changing controls for my c# game using strings derived from text boxes.

```
 moverighttext = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\moverighttext.txt");
 movelefttext = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\movelefttext.txt");

 //I have the letter 'D' Stored in moverighttext.txt and the letter 'A' Stored in movelefttext.txt

 var moverightkey = (Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), moverighttext);
 var moveleftkey = (Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), movelefttext); 

 if (KeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.moveleftkey))
            if (KeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.moverightkey))
            {
                acceleration.X = 0;
            }
```

This produces the errors:- 
'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys' does not contain a definition for 'moveleftkey'

'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys' does not contain a definition for 'moverightkey'

I'm new to using things like 'Enum.Parse', but I was under the impression that I had added 'moverightkey'
and 'moveleftkey' as definitions to 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys'.

I'm looking to resolve these errors or find the correct way of handling this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Keys` is an enum and `moveleftkey` is not one of the values. However, `moveleftkey` - after parsing - **is** the enum value (or should be).

Remove the `Keys.` prepending `moveleftkey` and `moverightkey` and give that a try.

I would recommend simplifying your assignment of control keys as well. You certainly do not need to create multiple files.

Copy the following to an Xml file (`control_keys.xml` for instance):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<control_keys>
    <move_left key="l"/>
    <move_right key="r"/>
    <!-- add more control keys -->
</control_keys>
```

Load that xml and get `Keys` as follows:  (see here for learning how to use [Linq-to-Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx))

```
var conrolKeys = XDocument.Load("control_keys.xml").Root;
//  now get your Keys text values
var moveLeftText = controlKeys.Element("move_left").Attribute("key").Value;
var moveRightText = controlKeys.Element("move_right").Attribute("key").Value;
//  now get your Keys values
var moveLeftKey = (Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), moveLeftText);
var moveRightKey = (Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), moveRightText);
```

**Edit per comment regarding namespaces**
Add project references to:

- System.Xml
- System.Linq.Xml

Visual Studio should then assist in resolving your `using` statements. But, in short:

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Linq.Xml;
```

Comment: Oh wow, this really is a much better way of doing it. I've never used .xml files, but this is awesome.

Comment: There are other ways to do the same, but I felt the 'long way' would be easiest to learn. :) Glad to help out.

Comment: Little question: what namespaces do I need to set as 'Using' to make this work?

Comment: Edited and added the requested info.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need an individual text file for every key in the game. Instead, you can use one text file of a suitable format (Binary, XML etc..) and parse that to get all the key information (look up `Serialization` for more information about this).

Assuming the `Enum.Parse` call was successful, you don't need to prefix `Keys` to `moveleftkey` because it's already a `Keys` enum. You can just call it like this

```
if (KeyboardState.IsKeyDown(moveleftkey))
```

Comment: Thanks for the information about Serialization, I'll look into it right away.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have your enums parsed (into the `moverightkey` and `moveleftkey` variables), you do not want to prefix them with `Keys`. This is only necessary if you are directly accessing specific Key values. Remember that the `Keys` enum represents actual keys on a keyboard. While there is an "A" key, there is no "moveleft" key. You can, however, create a variable called `moveleftkey` and assign it the value `Keys.A`.

e.g.:

```
if (KeyboardState.IsKeyDown(moveleftkey)) 
{

}
```